# Is there a Ruby documentation tool that allows inclusion of diagrams and images?

Tags: ruby, doxygen, documentation-generation, rdoc, yard

I am a big fan of [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) which I have used for years with various languages. In particular, I appreciate its wiki-like ability to [include images](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdimage) and run the Graphviz dot generator to have arbitrary inline diagrams from [inline DOT code](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddot) or [external files](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddotfile).

[RDoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net) has diagramming support to generate class diagrams using Graphviz but I can't see any way to include arbitrary images or diagrams. Neither does it appear to support building up arbitrary pages like oxygen.

Is there *any* tool which provides these Doxygen-style features for Ruby?

I have skimmed the Ruby Toolbox [list of tools](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/documentation_tools.html) and they all seem to be variants of RDoc.

The most likely solution for me at present seems to be [extending Yard](http://yard.soen.ca/getting_started.html#extending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was told at a [Perth Agile Meetup](http://www.perthagilemeetupgroup.com.au/calendar/14469833/) last week, graphviz integration is [now available](http://gnuu.org/2008/02/29/generating-class-diagrams-with-yard-and-graphviz/) as a branch of yard.

Answer (score 1):

RDoc will automatically convert urls to html links and urls which point to image files are automatically converted to html images.